# Why won't Chrome delete all my cookies when I quit?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Using the latest Google Chrome on Windows 10, Kubuntu 18.04 (Version 88.0.4324.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and a Chromebook (Chrome OS 88 stable) I have the same problem.  I've configured Chrome to "Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome" and yet some cookies persist after quit and even reboot. (Most cookies are deleted).

I have "Block third-party cookies" set, and I've whitelisted some entries, such as google ones, via:

[*.]google.co.uk
(including third parties)

so that I don't get logged out, Chrome syncing doesn't get paused, etc.
I've tried some of the sugg I've seen online such as:

- Making sure I have no tabs open
- Having chrome not run in the background upon quit (where supported by OS) Disable all extensions
- Disable preloading of sites

But it makes no difference.

This is an example of one of the sites:
[www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com)

```
Origin               https://www.reddit.com
Persistent storage   None
Temporary storage    0 B
```

Although empty, it's still there!   Most of the others aren't empty. They're a mixture of "Cookies", "local storage" and "file system".  I don't see any obvious pattern to describe why a few remain.

Comment: Isn't that what incognito mode is for?

Comment: Get Nirsoft Cookie View for Chrome. I have about 3,000 cookies on my Edge system but cookies facilitate easy (and useful) work.

Comment: @Moab By configuring Chrome the way I am I shouldn't need to.  I don't want to have to remember to do that every time I open every single website.  I want the ability to flush everything away when I quit except for the few sites I want to stay logged into for convenience (ie the site stores my preferences in cookies, not in my account on the server).   Seems like this problem is caused by a bug but I was wondering if I'm missing some reason why this behaviour exists, or if this is a known problem with a workaround.

Comment: @John Thanks, but I don't need an extension to delete the cookies (plus you can't install extensions on Chrome for Android).  Most of them are being deleted and the handful which persist are easily deleted through Chrome's UI.